# Shows Call to a member function format() on boolean error in php after editing

Tags: php

Here is the original script

```
<?php

$monthToAdd = 36;

$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-04-10');

$year = $d1->format('Y');
$month = $d1->format('n');
$day = $d1->format('d');

$year += floor($monthToAdd/12);
$monthToAdd = $monthToAdd%12;
$month += $monthToAdd;
if($month > 12) {
    $year ++;
    $month = $month % 12;
    if($month === 0)
        $month = 12;
}

if(!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j', $year.'-'.$month.'-1');
    $d2->modify('last day of');
}else {
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-d', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
}
$d2->setTime($d1->format('H'), $d1->format('i'), $d1->format('s'));

echo $d2->format('d-m-Y');

?>
```

and here is the one that I edited

```
<?php

$y = 2016;
$m = 04;
$d = 10;
$monthToAdd = 36;

$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '$y-$m-$d');

$year = $d1->format('Y');
$month = $d1->format('n');
$day = $d1->format('d');

$year += floor($monthToAdd/12);
$monthToAdd = $monthToAdd%12;
$month += $monthToAdd;
if($month > 12) {
    $year ++;
    $month = $month % 12;
    if($month === 0)
        $month = 12;
}

if(!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j', $year.'-'.$month.'-1');
    $d2->modify('last day of');
}else {
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-d', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
}
$d2->setTime($d1->format('H'), $d1->format('i'), $d1->format('s'));

echo $d2->format('d-m-Y');

?>
```

it give error

Idea is to add X value as month , show the result.
For example the date provided is "2016-04-10" and $monthToAdd = 4; , it should give a result of 2016-08-10

script was working , but I just want to add a form so that user can input month to calculate.
I am new to php, anyone help ?

Comment: What is the exact error message and the line referenced?

Comment: Read up about [strings](http://php.net/string). Single quotes won't interpolate variables.

Comment: @Technoh , ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\wamp\www\2\index.php on line 10

Comment: You get the error because `DateTime::createFromFormat()` is returning `bool(false)`. See answers below for the *fix*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for php to parse variables within stings properly, you must wrap them in double quote marks (").

Change

```
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '$y-$m-$d');
```

to

```
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "$y-$m-$d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this

```
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '$y-$m-$d');
```

to

```
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "$y-$m-$d");
```

php won't parse values inside of ' but it will inside of "

Hope that helps, if not, could you please pass on the exact error, and the line that it references.